# change hostname from text in .txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am making a script that if the computer starts up, the hostname has to change to a specific name. That name is in a test.txt file.

Currently I have a test.txt file in my documents.

If I do :

```dos
setlocal
set /p hostname=< test.txt
echo %hostname% 
SBB-TEST
```

So I can have the text from the .txt file into a variable. 
But If I try :

```dos
WMIC computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name =%hostname%
```

I get the error : Invalid Verb Switch

That is my first question.

My second question is, If I do this directly from a batch file.. I get following error on my screen :

```dos
set /p hostname= 0<test.txt
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Why does he change the set /p hostname=< test.txt to set /p hostname= 0

The 0 is nowhere specified.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: For your second question, I don't get any error. Does the actual filename contains space or special characters? The 0 represents a STDIN. One doesn't have to add `0` because the `<` implicit to read from STDIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CALL on the `rename`. You will still need to reboot the system for the new hostname to take effect.

```
WMIC computersystem where name="%computername%" CALL rename name =%hostname%
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/02/19/renaming-a-computer-using-wmic-and-how-to-get-around-that-aggravating-invalid-global-switch-error/

Also, `HOSTNAME` is already an environment variable under UNIX/Linux/Cygwin. I would call this one something else. Perhaps `NEW_HOSTNAME`.